# detection of selected text not working properly

Tags: javascript, selection, highlight

I am trying detect, with javascript, if a text inside a `div` formatted as a `textarea` is selected or not. The HTML is this:

```
<div id="rte-test" class="rich-text-editor">
    <ul class="toolbar">
        <li> <a href="#" class="command" id="...">...</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="textarea" id="textareaContent" contentEditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this javascript code:

```
var command = document.getElementsByClassName("command");

for(var i=0; i<command.length; i++) {
  command[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var btn = this;
    var content = window.document.getElementById("textareaContent");
    if (content.getSelection) {
      console.log(content.getSelection() + ' selected. ' + btn.id);
    } else {
      console.log('nothing is selected. ' + btn.id);
    }
  });
}
```

with this code only the "nothing is select" option is reached by the `if/else` even if something is selected on the `textarea`.

I also tried this:

```
var command = document.getElementsByClassName("command");

for(var i=0; i<command.length; i++) {
  command[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var btn = this;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      console.log(window.getSelection() + ' selected. ' + btn.id);
    } else {
      console.log('nothing is selected. ' + btn.id);
    }
  });
}
```

with this code only the "selected" option is reached by the `if/else` even if nothing is selected.

Anyone have any idea of how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    if (window.getSelection().toString()) {
      console.log(window.getSelection() + ' selected. ' + btn.id);
    } else {
      console.log('nothing is selected. ' + btn.id);
    }
```

`window.getSelection()` returns a non empty object which will always be true as it is not empty. When you put `window.getSelection()` into `console.log`, `toString()` is automatically called.